# Configuring Hipache with etcd

Tags: docker, coreos, etcd, hipache

I recently found out that Hipache can now work with etcd.

I have the following Hipache config:

```
{
    "server": {
        "accessLog": "/tmp/access.log",
        "port": 80,
        "workers": 10,
        "maxSockets": 100,
        "deadBackendTTL": 30,
        "tcpTimeout": 30,
        "retryOnError": 3,
        "deadBackendOn500": true,
        "httpKeepAlive": false
    },
    "driver": ["etcd://172.17.42.1:4001"]
}
```

My question is regarding the `"driver": ["etcd://172.17.42.1:4001"]` bit.

Is there anyway that I can instruct the Hipache machine to dynamically attach itself to any member of the etcd cluster?

My current CoreOS setup all etcd nodes are on a different node and etcd is not running on every node in the CoreOS cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Kubernetes[1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes), you could specify either a static service IP or a domain using skydns[2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns).

Comment: Thanks @Sendai.

However, I resolved my issue. Correct Config:

"driver": ["etcd://172.17.42.1:4001,etcd://172.17.42.5"]